# Server side pagination in jquery datatable with client side sorting and filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Datatables requirements, is it possible?
Example Scenario:
1. Server returns 10 rows at a time.
2. Pagination is to be used
3. Going back to a previous rendered page does not reload the data from the server
4. Sorting should be configurable enough to work on the already loaded data only and do not query the server for it
5. Filtering should be configurable to work on client side data or query the server for it.

Is this set of requirements possible with jquery Datatables?

Comment: Does pipelining help in some way (http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)

Answer (score 1):

OK, the answer is this: if you use server-process to get data then when you do the sort, pagination and filter, it will always get data from server side, you have no chance to do it just in client side. When I used it first time, I had the same requirement, but finally I gave it up. in brief, if you choose server side, it will take care all of things with server side data.